# Colouring a legend on a PCA plot

Tags: r, plot, pca

I have a large data matrix which can be partitioned by a variable called 'Day' which varies from 1-10 and I want to use this to colour my PCA plot

This works fine when I use the following code:

```
plot(pca$x,col = day,pch=20)
```

But when I try to add a legend showing which day each colour refers to:

```
legend("topleft", pch = 20, col=day, legend = c("Day 1","Day 2","Day 3","Day 4","Day 5","Day 6","Day 7","Day 8","Day 9","Day 10"), bty='n', cex=.75)
```

I get this. How do I get the legend to display the individual colours on the plot??:
[image]

Comment: That is probably because `day` contains as many colors as datapoints, but for the legend you only need ten. Maybe `unique(day)` is enough, but it really depends on how your data is organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
legend("topleft", col=1:10, legend = paste("Day", 1:10),
    pch = 20, bty='n', cex=.75)
```

To clean things up a bit. The legend should only specify the distinct colors you are using in the plot.

Answer (score 1):

For mtcars this would work:

```
with(mtcars, plot(mpg, wt, col=cyl))
with(mtcars, legend("topright", pch = 20, col=unique(cyl), legend = unique(cyl)))
```

Maybe you can do it the same way with your data.

Or if you use ggplot2:

```
qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars, colour=factor(cyl))
```